# Sort an array of doubles and return the sorted array of original indices

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sorting, quicksort

I want to sort an array of doubles but I want to save the original indices. I have tried the following -

```
double[] circs = new double[noOfCircs];
```

Initialize circs with values...

```
int[] loc = Enumerable.Range(0, noOfCircs-1).ToArray();
Array.Sort(circs, loc);
```

After sorting, I want to use the array loc for further calculations.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sorting array is value position changing in the array and that means index will change. To save previous positions you will need different collection to store value and original index.

Comment: I am using a different array for storing the index. The array 'loc' in the code shared above is used to store index values.

Comment: Just for my understanding. You have `double[]` with values that you want sorted. But you don't want to change that original array, so you're trying to save the indicies of the original array in a sorted way to an `int[]` ? Have you tried to create a sorted `double[]` array copy of the original one, iterate through the new one, find the values in the old array and save their index to the loc array?

Comment: `var result = circs.Select((s,i) => new { Value = s, Index = i }).OrderBy(o => o.Value);` this will return an ordered collection (IOrderedEnumerable) of anonymous object, which you can use as you desire. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Vulpex You are right for the purposes of this discussion. :)

I have ~10000 values in the double array. I thought using the Sort method would be faster than iterating through the lot of them. Am I wrong?

Besides, like I said, I have further operations to perform once I have the sorted indices.

Comment: @SeM - I'm not sure I understand your explanation entirely. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @arzee If you can use Linq and I'm not 100% sure about performance (you can check it by yourself), first part `circs.Select((s,i) => new { Value = s, Index = i })` will create a collection of `IEnumerable<'a>` (where `'a` is an anonymous type containing `Value` and `Index`), second part sorting that new collection by `Value`. You will have `IOrderedEnumerable<'a> result` at the end, which will contain your array ordered and the indexes before.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `Sort method would be faster than iterating through the lot of them` What did you mean by that? Please edit your question, add details what are you trying to do, what you have done, what was wrong and what was the expected result.

Comment: @arzee maybe [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EqiRU1) is what you're looking for? Not the most efficient but it works.

Comment: What is not working? I can tell that the 2nd argument to Range is wrong but what's the problem that you identified?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest *Linq* with a help of *anonymous classes*:

```
using System.Linq;

...

double[] circs = ...

int[] loc = circs
  .Select((value, index) => new { // for each item we store
     value = value,               //   its value
     index = index                //   and original index
   })
  .OrderBy(pair => pair.value)  // Order by values
  .Select(pair => pair.index)   // By return original index
  .ToArray();
```

Comment: It would be interesting to do a performance comparison between this solution with anonymous types and with C# 7 value tuples. The value tuples would copy more memory but have better locality (and produce less collection pressure), so it is hard to say which one would be more performant without trying it.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert double array to list and then sort the list instead. That way you'll still have your original double array.

```
 List<double> list = doubleArray.ToList();
 list.Sort();
```